# "Scope" of being blocked from asking

Tags: support, deleted-questions, asking-questions, stackexchange, post-ban

As you know well, when one attempts to delete a question that has already received an answer, the following message is displayed.

"Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?"

---

**Question:** Is this sentence referring to all sites/communities of https://stackexchange.com/sites, or just the single site/community where the user is deleting a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FAQ post "[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997)" contains the following paragraph:

> ### Will a ban on one Stack Exchange site affect my standing on other sites in the network?
>
> No, post bans are considered separately per site. Your activity on one site will only affect post bans on that one site, and will not affect your standing on other sites. This does mean that you [cannot lift a ban on one site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255870/does-positive-activity-on-one-se-site-help-to-get-out-of-a-ban-on-another-site) by contributing positively on another site.

Answer (score 3):

This refers to the so-called [question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232) and it's **per site**; your questions on MathOverflow do not influence your ability to ask questions on other Stack Exchange sites. Not even Meta MathOverflow; it's perfectly possible to ask Meta questions while being question-banned on the main site.

Another informative article is [this Help Center article](https://mathoverflow.net/help/question-bans). It doesn't explicitly mention the question ban is per site, and it's hard to prove a negative, but I've seen countless questions on Meta Stack Exchange by users complaining about their question ban on Stack Overflow. That wouldn't be possible if the ban somehow extended network-wide.